# Send data from js to php in the same file (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send data from a js to the php. Here is the code i tried (you can ignore the part where i get data from index.php).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let dat = {
            "Review": {
                "Product": 1}
        };
        let url = "/Backend/api/index.php";
        let uri = "test.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: dat,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                let json = $.parseJSON(data);
                let string = "";
                for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    string += json[i]["IDReview"] + "," + json[i]["dtDescription"] + "," + json[i]["dtStars"] + ",";
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: uri,
                    data: dat,
                    type: 'POST'});
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that after i send the query the POST array is still empty (or it isnt shown because i need to reload the php) can someone help me ?

Comment: The is no question. And no the title is not a question rather than a sentence.  So what is the question. What is the result you are getting running that particular code. Do you get any errors? Please update your question and please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you want to check that the data you are posting to the server is making it into the `$_POST` array, you can add `echo json_encode($_POST);` to the endpoints you are posting data to then in your ajax success function, use `console.log(variable_for_data)` to log the data returned from the server in the browser console. Let's say you posted something like `{"value1": "some data", "value2":"something else"}` using an ajax function to the server, echoing back the JSON encoded `$_POST` array should return the same data.